# Two curves not joined at same point

Tags: pgfplots

I have been trying to plot two functions that represent a rotated ellipse in cartesian coordinates. However, the point where these two curves meet do not look as they are "joined" or closed. Is there any way to fix this? I don't know why is this.[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
y axis line style={<->},
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$y$}
]
\addplot[-] expression[line width=0.4,smooth,samples=200,domain=0:49.999] {sqrt((1.38^(2.0)-0.5^(2.0))*(50.0*(x)-(x)^(2.0)))+0.5*(x)};
\addplot[-] expression[line width=0.4,smooth,samples=200,domain=0:49.999] {-sqrt((1.38^(2.0)-0.5^(2.0))*(50.0*(x)-(x)^(2.0)))+0.5*(x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Please, add the rest of code so we can compile it.

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why but you might have to adjust the domain properly, I suppose. Here is a (non elegant) work around using `shorten`.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
y axis line style={<->},
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$y$}
]
\addplot[shorten >= -0.5ex,smooth,line width=0.4pt,samples=300,domain=0:49.99999999999999999999] {sqrt((1.38^(2.0)-0.5^(2.0))*(50.0*(x)-(x)^(2.0)))+0.5*(x)};
\addplot[shorten >= -0.5ex,smooth,line width=0.4pt,samples=300,domain=0:49.99999999999999999999] {-sqrt((1.38^(2.0)-0.5^(2.0))*(50.0*(x)-(x)^(2.0)))+0.5*(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plot can also be done by using a parameter variable (t in the example)
The advantage is that the points are more evenly distributed, thus fewer samples are needed and the path can be closed (`smooth cycle`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[ticks=none,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={<->},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$y$}
  ]
    \def\xzero{25}
    \def\yzero{12.5}
    \def\RotPhi{66}
    \def\RadiusA{36.5}
    \def\RadiusB{22}
    \addplot[
      line width=.4,
      smooth cycle,
      variable=t,
      samples=100,
      domain=0:360,
    ] ({
      \xzero + \RadiusA*cos(\RotPhi)*cos(t) - \RadiusB*sin(\RotPhi)*sin(t)
    }, {
      \yzero + \RadiusA*sin(\RotPhi)*cos(t) + \RadiusB*cos(\RotPhi)*sin(t)
    })
    ; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Very elegant solution, but will have to redefine my function with an equivalent mathematical expression as you did.